# Understanding the trancitor (transfer capacitor)

Tags: transistors, capacitor, trancitor

In one of my lecture class, one of my electronics professor told a little about a new technology called "trancitor" and told it is opposite of transistor.

He asks us to learn more about it on our own. When I googled it, it just shows that I have mistyped "transistor".

Was my professor wrong? If not any information regarding this would be great.

Edit: I found [this report](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1805/1805.05842.pdf) regarding this topic.

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I googled it, it just shows that I have mistyped "tranistor".Was my professor wrong? If not any sort of idea regarding this would be great.

You can improve your "Google-fu" in this type of situation, by enclosing the search word in quotation marks - so search for "trancitor" (with those quotation mark characters) and you will find several pages listed for that term, including this Wikipedia page as a starting point:

[Wikipedia - Trancitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trancitor) - which includes this paragraph:

> The term, *Trancitor*, and its concept were first conceived by Sungsik Lee, a professor at the Department of Electronics Engineering, Pusan National University, South Korea, through his article, entitled *A Missing Active Device — Trancitor for a New Paradigm of Electronics*, in arXiv uploaded on 30 April 2018.

As mentioned in Wikipedia: *A Missing Active Device — Trancitor for a New Paradigm of Electronics* by Sungsik Lee, arXiv:1805.05842 [physics.app-ph] - links to arXiv: [abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05842) and [PDF download](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.05842)

Comment: thank you sir ! I really got a new way to upgrade my search technique in google, and of course regarding this new "transfer-capacitor"

Comment: Sam, I don't have enough reputation yet to create a trancitor tag.  Would you be willing to do it?  I think for an odd new component name it will come in useful one day.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I'll try again.  The page I found indicated it was a 1500 rep privilege but it wasn't specific to EE.SE.

Comment: @KH - Thanks for the reply. I've created the tag and also added details for that tag into the tag wiki, with links to the Wikipedia article and the arXiv page where people can download the original research paper (as given in my answer). My newly-created tag wiki entry needs to be reviewed before it becomes live, but it should become viewable in due course. So, thanks for the suggestion to make this topic a new tag :-)